# How to parse HTML content to Jenkins parameters through groovy script?

Tags: html, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I have created a dynamic text-box though Active choices Reactive reference parameter.
I want to parse the content that user enters in this dynamic textbox to the build section of the Jenkins.

Below is what I have done till now
[image: Sample UI Screen 1]

When the User selects "City" as input a textbox populates as shown below
[image: Sample UI Screen 2]

Below is the groovy script used to populate the dynamic input box

```
if (Country.equals("City")) {

html=
'''<!DOCTYPE HTML>
      <input type = "text"
             id = "myText"
   />
  </p>

  </html>
  '''
  return html
  } 

else
  {
  return ["Invalid"]
  }
```

I want to parse the content "Delhi" to build section of Jenkins.I have tried  ${path} or $path, $html, $id but it is not accessible.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got the solution

Code snippet

```
if (Country.equals("city")) {

html=
'''
<p>
   <input type = "text" id = "myText" name="value" >
</p>
<hr>
'''
return html

} 

else
{
return ["Invalid"]
}
```

The value passed in the text box path can be directly parsed as $path in the execute shell option.

Comment: how came with that code I´m getting 2 times the value of the variable and and a "comma" (,) at the end like this. I just put letter a and b on text boxes

+ echo a,
a,
[Pipeline] sh
[workspace] Running shell script
+ echo b,
b,

Comment: got the answer here https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40179

Comment: Where is "path" declared?